# Chrome local storage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I've inherited a chrome app that acts as a client and connects to a server using an api key. The api key is typed in by the user and the stored in local storage. We've had reports that in certain events (power failures, network connection loss, etc.) the client loses its pairing key. I don't know much about Chrome apps and local storage, but is this a common thing? I've been trying to read up on local storage in Chrome and it doesn't seem like one of these events should wipe out the local storage, so am I missing something here? I haven't been able to reproduce the issue myself, but it seems to be a pretty common one among our customers.

Edit: If I had to formulate a single question it would be: Has anyone had issues with chrome extensions local storage being erased after events like power or network connection loss?

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: Ok, I tried to do so.

Comment: Clarify further: extension or app? `chrome.storage` or `localStorage`?

Comment: Looking at the code, they are using chrome.storage.local. It's an app.